# What is the difference between font and font family?

Tags: fonts

Is there a clear distinction between font and font family, for example can we consider Arial to be a font family, but Arial Regular to be a font?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could consider Arial a synonym for Arial regular, since it's what people usually mean when talking about Arial, or you could consider Arial regular a subset of the larger Arial family that also includes Arial bold, Arial narrow etc. The modern terminology is not clear-cut, but in traditional terms Arial and Arial regular are not fonts:

> In traditional typography, a font is a particular size, weight and style of a typeface. Each font was a matched set of metal type, one piece (called a "sort") for each glyph, and a typeface comprised a range of fonts that shared an overall design.
>
> In modern usage, with the advent of digital typography, "font" is frequently synonymous with "typeface", although the two terms do not necessarily mean the same thing.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is, sort of. Let’s clarify the **terminology** first: "typeface" and "font" are usually used interchangeably to mean the same thing. Frequently, when people and user interfaces refer to “font”, they actually mean the “typeface” or artistic shape of the characters, such as *Arial* or *Times New Roman*.

More correctly, “font” means the file on the system that represents a given typeface. So, when we say that a font is installed, we mean that the file exists in the designated location for the system. And a “font family” represents a collection of related fonts, such as bold and italic variations of the same “typeface” or “font”.

In summary, in common terminology, typeface (aka font) means the design, font means the file containing the typeface, and font-family means collection of related fonts. This comes from a [How-To Geek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/325644/whats-the-difference-between-a-font-a-typeface-and-a-font-family/) that explains it nicely.

Now, let’s talk **CSS**. The `font-family` is used to specify the typeface only, either one, or a stack of multiple typefaces, so that there is one or more fallback choices in case of font unavailability. For example:

```
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

However, it is often convenient to use the shorthand `font` to set other related parameters such as `font-size`, `font-weight` etc in a single line. For example, this will set both the font size and the font family stack:

```
font: 1.5em Georgia, Arial, sans-serif;
```

You can read more on the MDN documentation for [font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font) and [font-family](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what is a **font series** then?

Comment: Thanks, I am not familiar with "font series". Perhaps you could cite a reference or text that uses this terminology so I can get some context.

Comment: I only have a vague memory of this term, so there may not be such a term. Maybe `\mdseries` and `\bfseries` in this [article](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_sizes,_families,_and_styles)?

Comment: Looked at the link, but still none the wiser. So, I don't know what "font series" is, if there's such a thing.

Comment: No problem! Thank you for the help!